# jQuery JSONP - error with a callback outside done()

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I'm on jQuery 1.8.2 and I'm doing a JSONP call like this:

```
    function foo(data) {
      console.log(data)
    }

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: http://xxx.cloudfront.net/posts.json?category=News&callback=foo,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      cache: true,
      jsonp: false
    }).done(function (data) {

    }).fail(function (XHR, status, error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

When I run this the proper data response gets returned to the foo callback. But the error also fires, and the console logs the error as `Error {}`. From reading elsewhere on Stackoverflow  it appears this is because the response is wrapped in the callback and jQuery's expecting plain JSON. Should I just ignore this error?

Comment: It is impossible that a promise fires both `done` and `fail` handlers.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be firing done - but the response gets passed as an argument to foo().

Comment: How does a querystring parameter get used as a function call???

Comment: @AndFinally: Why did you use that `foo` function instead of the `done` callback?

Comment: @Bergi I see now that was wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have a global function `foo` that is the callback, but [let jQuery create that global function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) automatically and pass the result to the `done` callbacks. It does expect that its own function gets called, otherwise it triggers the error.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: "http://xxx.cloudfront.net/posts.json?category=News&callback=?",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonpCallback: 'foo', // for caching
  cache: true
}).done(function (data) {
  console.log(data);
}).fail(function (XHR, status, error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Good catch on the `foo` function.

Comment: Thanks Bergi - when I rewrite it as you suggest it works a treat.

Comment: Hm, my colleague's just told me we specified our own callback because we needed responses to be cached.

Comment: @AndFinally: You can use the `jsonpCallback` parameter for that.

Answer (score 1):

You've specifically removed the JSONP callback from your AJAX call, try omitting `jsonp : false` from the options object you pass into `$.ajax` and then removing the callback function you've created (`foo`) and let jQuery do the work for you.

Documentation is found here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/