# jquery ajax, backbone, jsonp callback not defined

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, jsonp

```
sync: function(method, model, options) {
  options.dataType = 'jsonp';
  options.cache = true;
  options.jsonp = 'callback';
  options.jsonpCallback = "inflchallcb";
  return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
},
```

results in

api call

```
https://url.tld?callback=inflchallcb
```

server response is

```
inflchallcb({...})
```

with

```
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8
```

results in error:

```
ReferenceError: inflchallcb is not defined at eval (eval at
```

jquery v 1.11.1 backbone 1.3.3

I have no clue.

Comment: Is `inflchallcb` defined as a global function in the javascript?

Comment: no, jquery is supposed to create the function see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833197/jquery-jsonp-error-with-a-callback-outside-done/18833245#18833245

i have however, tried doing just that, and it has no effect on the error output

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ghtuma24/
example with no global callback

Comment: Please you "tags" to refer technologies included, not the title...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after adding some console.logs to the jquery source, I realized there were two concurrent requests being made, each attaching and removing the same global function, i had to make the global function unique but also cacheable for each request.